# Current-Steering Circuit

Tags: amplifier, differential

Can anyone help me solve the equation for I-reference? 
The final answer is given, but I don't know how it is obtained.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Homework.  What were you able to figure out yourself so far?

Comment: it is from the lecture notes, and I am trying to understand the concept

Comment: yes I did try but I got the polarity of VEE and VEB2 reversed

Comment: Eh, I'll give him credit for just not seeing this right. Sometimes you need a slap to uncross your eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base and collector of Q1 and Q2 are tied together.

$$V_{CC}+V_{EE}-V_{BE1}-V_{BE2}$$

is simply the voltage across R.

Edit to include comment discussion:
The voltage across R is just the total voltage drop in the current path, (Vcc + Vee) minus the other drops (Vbe1 + Vbe2). You are left with the drop across R, or

$$(V_{CC} + V_{EE}) - (V_{BE1}+V_{BE2})$$

Comment: yes I can see that , but how did you add these up?

Comment: Vee is given as "-Vee". I think that may be where you're confused.

Comment: Vcc + Vee is potential difference (voltage) between Q1's emitter and Q2's emitter

Comment: I can see the potential difference for Q1 which s VCC-VBE1 but I don't get the one for Q2

Comment: -Vee + Vbe2 right?

Comment: yes, that is correct. but why the polarity is reveresed?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: in the equation it is VEE-VBE2

Comment: Ok, so you gave the voltage at the top of R to be Vcc-Vbe1 and you agree that the voltage at the bottom of R is -Vee+Vbe2. So what happens when you calculate the voltage ACROSS R?

Comment: ((Vcc-Vbe1)-(Vbe2-Vee))=Vcc-Vbe1-Vbe2+Vee

Comment: So you understand now?